# Render customize component inside XTemplate

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

```
Ext.define('GB.view.DigestList',{
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias:'widget.digestlist',

            items:[ {
                xtype:'dataview',
                store: 'GB.store.Digests',
                tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
                          '<tpl for=".">',
                            '<div class="container">',
                              '{name}',
                              '<div class="davidfun"></div>',
                            '</div>',
                          '</tpl>'
                ),      
                listeners: {
                    viewready: function(){
                        var home_d = Ext.create('GB.view.MyOwnDigest');
                        home_d.render(Ext.query('.davidfun')[0]);
                        // home_d.render(Ext.getBody()); <- it'll work fine with this line
                    },
                }
              }],

    bind: function(record, store) {
        this.getComponent(0).bindStore(record);
    }

});


Ext.define('GB.store.Digests', {
    extend:'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'GB.model.Digest',
    data:[
        {'name':'name111'},
        {'name':'name222'}
    ]
});
```

Does someone know why can't i get div class which is "davidfun" that in Xtemplate by Ext.query('.davidfun')[0],

it'll always show 'undefined', thanks for your response first:)

Code UPDATE:

> > Problem resolved!

Comment: First note: XTemplates are compiled by default, you don'T need to set this.

Comment: ok, i'll modified for that. 
I was wondering if it didn't compiled therefore set that compiled: true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try the "viewready" event of the dataview.

See my example http://jsfiddle.net/2huvt/

Comment: hi again, but what if I change the data loading to proxy, it'll show undefined http://jsfiddle.net/LUuhZ/1/

Comment: Try the 'refresh' event of the dataview, but it will be called twice in your case. In the handler, you can do your Ext.query only if the store is loaded. BTW in your fiddle, browser won't allow you to do cross domain ajax to dropbox.