# Custom Component in Dataview

Tags: extjs, extjs6-classic

I would like to display a custom UI component for each record in a store.

It looks like a DataView is the best way to do this. There are a lot of old links stating how this is possible by using a DataViewItem but I cannot find anything in the current docs (I'm using version 6.0.2). Is this possible to do with extjs6? Here is what I have right now using a template:

```
var myTpl= new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div>My object is too complex to be displayed with simple html<div>',
    '</tpl>'   
);

Ext.define( 'MyProject.view.main.MyList', {
    extend: 'Ext.DataView',
    xtype: 'mylist',

    requires: [
        'MyProject.view.main.MyViewModel'
    ],

    viewModel: {
        type: 'myviewmodel'
    },

    bind: {
        store: '{store}'
    },

    // I don't want to do this. I would rather have something like this:
    // itemXType: 'myitem'
    itemTpl: myTpl,

} );
```

I've left out the viewModel implementation because the only thing it does is defines a proxy store. I can add it in if you need it.

Is there another way of accomplishing this? Maybe Something other than a dataview?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with ExtJS 6.0.2. Just take a look at [Touch 2.4 example](https://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/components/dataview.html). Thats an example of Touch 2.4 but it still works in ExtJS 6.0.2 with the modern toolkit. See this [Sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1h58) (I just copied the code from the Touch example there and selected ExtJS 6.0.2 - Modern toolkit). Regarding Docs: Maybe you are looking at the docs of the classic toolkit. There is no Ext.DataView but you could use Ext.view.View instead

Short version:
Use

```
 config: {
                defaultType: 'mydataitem',
                useComponents: true
            }
```

in your DataView.

Create a custom DataItem which extends

```
Ext.dataview.component.DataItem
```

and add there your desired components.

Comment: Ahh I actually am using the classic toolkit, which would explain that. Is there a way to do this with the classic version? The docs for View do not have any of these values...

Comment: I See. Thought you are using modern since you talked about DataView. Mabey that can help with Adaption to ExtJs 6 classic using Ext.view.View http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12597830/render-customize-component-inside-xtemplate

Comment: FYI: Ext.view.View is a dataview... it's been in extjs classic for almost a decade... that's where ST and Modern got it from.

Answer (score 0):

For Version above Ext 6.2 use `xtype: 'componentdataview'` instead of `xtype: 'dataview'`.
https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/Ext.dataview.Component.html